# invalid ALTER TABLE option when execute immediate statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, alter

> Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit
>
> Production PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
>
> "CORE 12.1.0.2.0  Production" TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version
>
> 12.1.0.2.0 - Production NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

This code working well

```
ALTER TABLE ACTIONLOG MODIFY (ID GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY START WITH 8);
```

but when I used with execute immediate giving error

```
declare 
mvalue INTEGER; 
exp varchar(1000);
begin 
select max(coalesce(ID,0))+1 into mvalue from ACTIONLOG; 
exp := 'ALTER TABLE ACTIONLOG MODIFY (ID GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY START WITH '|| mvalue ||');';
dbms_output.Put_line('Max Value: '|| mvalue);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Expression: ' || exp);
execute immediate exp; 
end;
/
```

DBMS Output

> Max Value: 8
>
> Expression: ALTER TABLE ACTIONLOG MODIFY (ID GENERATED
>   ALWAYS AS IDENTITY START WITH 8);

Error

> Error starting at line : 1 in command - declare  mvalue INTEGER;  exp
>
> varchar(1000); begin  select max(coalesce(ID,0))+1 into mvalue from
>
> ACTIONLOG;  exp := 'ALTER TABLE ACTIONLOG MODIFY (ID GENERATED ALWAYS
>
> AS IDENTITY START WITH '|| mvalue ||');'; dbms_output.Put_line('Max
>
> Value: '|| mvalue); DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Expression: ' || exp);
>
> execute immediate exp;  end; Error report - ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE
>
> option ORA-06512: at line 9
>
> 1735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
>
> *Cause:
>
> *Action:

Edit: The problem was ";"

So The answer is :

```
exp := 'ALTER TABLE ACTIONLOG MODIFY (ID GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY START WITH '|| mvalue ||');';
```

instead of

```
 exp := 'ALTER TABLE ACTIONLOG MODIFY (ID GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY START WITH '|| mvalue ||')';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
declare 
mvalue INTEGER; 
exp varchar(1000);
begin 
select max(coalesce(ID,0))+1 into mvalue from ACTIONLOG; 
--exp := 'ALTER TABLE ACTIONLOG MODIFY (ID GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY START WITH '|| mvalue ||');';
dbms_output.Put_line('Max Value: '|| mvalue);
--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Expression: ' || exp);
execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE ACTIONLOG MODIFY (ID GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY START WITH '|| mvalue ||')'; 
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you. Problem is ";" at end of statement.  When I removed  ";" my script is worked too. So: exp := 'ALTER TABLE ACTIONLOG MODIFY (ID GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY START WITH '|| mvalue ||')'; is correct too